# Is the Magic School Bus actually magic?

Tags: magic, science, the-magic-school-bus

Is The Magic School Bus, of the *The Magic School Bus* franchise, actually magic? On one hand, it's called magic and does many things that science probably can't achieve. On the other hand, it is only called magic by either children, or people talking to children and it would be odd for a science-based educational series to have a major magic element.

So is The Magic School Bus actually magic, or has [Clark's Third Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) come into effect and it's just really advanced science?

Comment: its a tardis that took the shape of a bus, its control panel has some familar dohickys and watcha macallits

Comment: An excellent question. A quick watch of the videos would suggest that there's some pseudo-science at work rather than actual magic.

Comment: Scholastic seem to be saying that *exploration and science are where the real magic lies*, rather than the bus itself. http://mediaroom.scholastic.com/press-release/scholastic-medias-magic-school-bus-continues-legacy-magic-school-bus-360-new-netflix-o

Comment: +1 for the new tag on a series that most of us probably read or watched at some point!

Comment: @Skooba I never even heard of it. Fancy [writing up a tag wiki](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/4831)? :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Done! I hope I did a good job!

Comment: Stop trying to ruin my childhood.

Comment: @Skooba Nice! I approved your edits.

Comment: As a corollary, was Mr. Wizard actually a wizard?

Comment: @Himarm So Ms Frizzle is a Time Lady? I can deal with that.

Comment: I wonder what Ms. Frizzle's thought process was when she first got the bus. "Well, I've got this amazing machine that can do almost anything-What should I do with it? I could revolutionize humanity by discovering the true origins of life and the universe, I could cure diseases, I could save the world from global warming... Nah, I'll just use it to teach children basic science facts.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Yes, almost certainly.

In the "Call the Producers" segment at the end of Episode 3, the Producer explicitly notes that Ms. Frizzle can't get sick because...

> ...she's magic

at which point we see an inexplicable sparkle coming off of her image on the screen.

Since magic (real magic) is evidently a part of the Magic Schoolbus 'verse, I think it's more plausible to assume that the bus (and its driver) are able to function *through the use of magic* rather than requiring the need for a further scientific explanation for the abilities they present.

Comment: The YouTube video is borked for me: "This video is no longer available because the YouTube account associated with this video has been terminated."

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Funny thing is, that video worked for me earlier today. Hopefully, being linked on Stack Exchange didn't trigger some auto-DMCA bots or something.

Comment: The YouTube account owning the video has been terminated.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ - Sorted. Try it now

Comment: @jpmc26 -  - Sorted. Try it now. I think the additional publicity got her account smashed. Hopefully this one will prove more resilient

Comment: @Richard Works for me

Comment: @Thunderforge - Alas, that account is also now terminated. Whoever owns the rights to that show must really really hate us.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes - It runs on magic gas:

Magic School Bus Inside a Hurricane:
[image: hrruicane amgic gas]

Comment: Hey Valorum, I think I bet you on this one ... :-)

Comment: "Magic" could just marketing. https://www.google.com/search?q=magic+product&tbm=isch

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish really. /sarc